# Is there a way to automatically convert C++ struct to google::protobuf::struct and vice-a-versa?

Tags: c++, struct, protocol-buffers

I am currently in a midst of a project where I have several C++ style structs e.g.

```
struct Object1 {
    int32_t member1;
    std::string member2;
    Object2 member3;
};
```

```
struct Object2 {
    int32_t member1;
    std::string member2;
    bool member3;
};
```

I am looking to publish the data stored by these structs over a grpc server using `google::protobuf::Struct` format. Is there a way to automate this? i.e. not fill in the proto struct manually e.g.

```
google::protobuf::Struct Object2;
auto fields = Object2->mutable_fields();
google::protobuf::Value value;
value.set_string_value("member2_value");
(*fields)["member2"] = value;
```

Currently have 60+ similar nested structs that have to be converted to proto structs!

Currently manually converting from C++ struct to `google::protobuf::Struct`

Comment: Why C tag? Can you compile your code using **C** compiler. If not do not spam tags

Comment: You normally start with the protobuf definition and generate the language specific definitions from it.

Comment: Why not invoke the proto compiler and get actual message types? Is the other end of the connection also using Struct rather than proper message definitions?

Comment: The **C/C++** language is derived from OCaml, and doesn't work with GPB, and hasn't been released to the public yet (...so how did you find out about it?!).  **C++** doesn't have reflection yet, but once it does then there will be a way to automatically convert (or generate) C++ to/from GBP.

Comment: Speak in terms of C ***or*** C++. Not both. C++ necessarily includes C features, but it's a separate language with additional capabilities, like the *namespaces used here*. C has no such thing.

Comment: Yes you can if you are willing to make a code generator pluging for protoc.